# How to handle external pop ups when pop up information is not present in HTML content page

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I am using selenium with python to automate the router page.

When I press the check box button will get one pop up which is not giving any information in HTML page.

Can you please guide me how to select "ok" button when that type of external popup comes?

Comment: Add your code trials

Comment: I tried to edit the question to make it a bit more understandable, but I still don't get what you mean by "get one pop up which is not giving any information in HTML page". Try adding a screenshot of the popup...

Comment: Are you talking about an alert?  Screenshot would help greatly here.

Answer (score -1):

Hi thank you all to replay for my question .i got the answer for this 
use below function to solve this 
    alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        alert.accept()